# Maven + Git Bash: Root directory path is being appended to Environment Variable value beginning with '/'

Tags: maven-3, git-bash

I'm setting an environment variable with the value `/abc/`, and then using that environment variable's value inside a Maven `pom.xml`.

When I run any Maven goal, eg. `mvn test`, inside Git Bash, the value of that environment variable is being translated to `C:/Users/<user>/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/abc/`.

As you can see, the `/` at the beginning is being replaced with the root directory's path. The `/`at the end is not being affected, so this only happens if the `/` occurs at the beginning.

Is there any way to prevent this? I just want to be able to use the environment variable's value as `/abc/` in the actual automated test being executed by Maven.

This is how I'm setting the env variable:
`export TEST="/abc/"`

This is how I'm using the env variable in `pom.xml`:

```
<properties>
    <testProp>${env.TEST}</testProp>
</properties>
```

**Versions:**
Maven: 3.6.0
Java: 1.8.0_212
Git Bash: 2.9.2
Mintty: 2.0.3

Answer (score 0):

git bash is designed only for git (and a few quirk like openssl etc). It is not meant for everyday bash shell.

I was also quite upset when I learnt that.

For Windows 7, just use Windows cmd (or powershell). Cygwin also can't help much either but babun (now un-maintained) works pretty well.

For Windows 10, just use Windows Subsystem for Linux and use Ubuntu shell.